# Can I access laravel project running in localhost from other devices on same network?

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, localhost, port

I have a laravel project running on localhost and want to know if it possible to access it from other devices on the same network with no need to do anything on these devices except entering the url of the project?

I tried to access it using main device ip and the port my laravel application using but it returns it takes too long to respond or something like that.

Comment: php artisan serve --host=urip --port=8000 .in urip place use your wifi ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the ip address of the machine where the project is running from, i use

`ifconfig` on a mac, then run the command below

```
php artisan serve --host=ip_address --port=****
```

replace **** with the port number eg, 8001

so it can be something like,

```
php artisan serve --host=ip_address --port=8001
```